# Best First search TSP fails on rectangle and wins on circle why?

Tags: algorithm, graph, traveling-salesman

In the Traveling Salesman Problem, this guy needs to go to N cities, he does not care specifically about the order, but he care about the **total distance**.

Suppose that the cities are places in a **circle** where the distance is **equal** among all cities and placed on **two parallel lines** that a are closer apart than the cities along the lines.

[image]

> The authors claim that the Best-First Search algorithm works well on
>   the circle but not in the case of two parallel lines it will fail to
>   find the best solution because this strategy will make it zig-zag from
>   one line to the other while the perfect solution is a rectangle. In
>   this specific example, the winning strategy consists in trying the
>   2-best-first cities at every branch.

---

I really didn't understand why would it fail, Why would the algorithm zig-zag in the first place? and why would it function correctly in the case of a circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best-First Search will of cause also find the best solution for the rectangle. But it will take a long time, because it will find a lot of bad solutions before finding the optimal solution.

On a circle the Best-First Search the first found solution is the best solution. Because going around is the best solution. And if you always take the nearest other point, you will never cross through the inner part of the circle which would not be optimal.